# Error installing libcamera

Tags: 21.04

I am trying to install Libcamera on my Ubuntu 21.04 setup. I followed a tutorial and ran

```
$ pip3 install --user meson
$ pip3 install --user --upgrade meson
$ git clone https://git.libcamera.org/libcamera/libcamera.git
$ cd libcamera
$ CC=clang CXX=clang++ meson build -Dpipelines=uvcvideo,ipu3 -Dprefix=/usr
$ ninja -C build
$ sudo ninja -C build install
```

but I got an error message

```
ninja: Entering directory `build'
[1/2] Installing files.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/mesonmain.py", line 140, in run
   return options.run_func(options)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/minstall.py", line 554, in run
   installer.do_install(datafilename)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/minstall.py", line 359, in do_install
   d = self.check_installdata(pickle.load(ifile))
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'OctalInt' on <module 'mesonbuild.coredata' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/coredata.py'>
FAILED: meson-install 
/usr/bin/meson install --no-rebuild
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first please note that `libcamera` [is packaged for latest Ubuntu versions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/hirsute/libcamera).

To start using it you have to install needed development package by

```
sudo apt-get install libcamera-dev
```

If you really need to compile it from source - then enable Source Code repositories (*deb-src*) using Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and then get its build-dependencies by

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libcamera-dev
```

and then proceed with compilation.